# Moodle: receiving mobile notification with same content in subject and message

Tags: php, push-notification, moodle

I am trying to set up a moodle application, and somehow the mobile push notification that are sent to me is using the message on both the subject and message section. I am new to moodle and I am not sure which part could be triggering it. The example is given below:

Expected Result:

Subject: Great! You have received your badge!

Message: [Some explanation about the badge and where to check it]

Actual result:

Subject: [Some explanation about the badge and where to check it]

Message: [Some explanation about the badge and where to check it]

The subject is not used at all. Changing the message from moodle panel (badge/message) would cause the change to be applied to both subject and message.

Moodle version: 3.9.4

Can anyone let me know what could be causing this issue? I think I had made many modifications to the original app, and I have no clue which could be the cause of it.

UPDATE: Just to clarify, this is not about the change not being applied to the message when the change is made. This is about Moodle uses message body on both subject and body while sending the mobile notification to the users. The change is applied to the message, but such a change is applied to both body and subject as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moodle: the message modification is not fully applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73395687/moodle-the-message-modification-is-not-fully-applied)

Comment: @RussellEngland Would check tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @RussellEngland I just checked that page and found that the `messagesubject` and `messagebody` are using different strings. But when user is receiving a notification, they receives `messagebody` as both the subject and body. Guess those two are not the same issue.

Comment: @RussellEngland Turns out that didn't answer my question. It is Airnotifier which causes that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be an issue with Airnotifier. If anyone encounters it, you should go check the Airnotifier code first once you confirm you are not using the same content on both title and message on your Moodle notification tab.